# How do you open a file chooser in a chrome packaged app with Dart

Tags: dart, google-chrome-app, dart-js-interop

There don't appear to be any dart packages for this, so I'm using Javascript interop.  This is what I've got so far:

```dart
  js.scoped(() {
    done(entry) {
      print('ok');
    }
    js.context.doneCallback = new js.Callback.once(done);
    js.context.chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry(null, js.context.doneCallback);
  });
```

It's failing with:

> Uncaught Error: Invocation of form fileSystem.chooseEntry(object, object) doesn't match definition fileSystem.chooseEntry(optional object options, function callback)

So it seems the callback is being rejected because it's the wrong type.

Any ideas?

[chrome.fileSystem docs](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem.html)
Edit: Changed optional param back to null (I also tried Damien's suggestion below).

Edit: this code works now - thanks Damien!

```dart
  js.scoped(() {
    done(entry) { print('ok'); }
    js.context.chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry(null, new js.Callback.once(done));
  });
```

Edit2: [Updated code](https://gist.github.com/xxgreg/5428315) which opens a file chooser and reads the path from it. However I'm not sure how to use a javascript FileReader object via js_interop.

Edit3: See [discussion](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/d/msg/misc/D5hb02teYCU/ZbFLwqnESvYJ) on the Dart mailing list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However I'm not sure how to use a javascript FileReader object via js_interop.

I've implemented a very hacky solution to this, with a similar example to yours here:

https://gist.github.com/rmsmith/5878583

The way I've approached the issue is to implement the implicit interfaces of the types (File, FileEntry, FileReader) that exist in `dart:html`.  I throw `UnimplementedError` for many methods until I need them.

The issue in your gist was that you were calling `readAsText(blob, label)` with an instance of your own `FileEntry` type, but you need to pass a `Blob` or `File`.  Since the `FileReader` is in js, you actually need a js.Proxy to `Blob` or `File`.

Answer (score 2):

I guess {} does not create the map chooseEntry is expecting and you need to use js.map, like that:

```
chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry(js.map({'type': 'openWritableFile'}),
  js.context.doneCallback);
```

However, I have not been able to get a real file path on the disk with this method (I can get the file content, but the path is in a virtual file system).

Edit: I am actually using a function as the second parameter, like that:

```
chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry(js.map({'type': 'openWritableFile'}),
    new js.Callback.once((var fileEntry) {
  print('fullPath: ' + fileEntry.fullPath);
}));
```

Comment: I think this method is supposed to open a chooser. I would like the user to choose a file, and then read the content. I'm not interested in the pathname. Also docs say the first argument is optional, I played around with a few options, null should work. I think this is failing on the second argument which should be type function, but for some reason an object is being passed. http://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem.html   Thanks for the suggestion though ;)

Comment: Right, I was actually using a function as the second parameter. I remember having the same problems as you with the first one, though. I also didn't understand why an optional parameter was causing problems.

Comment: Yup - inlining the constructor call fixes it - bizarre. js.context must be wrapping the function in an object.